# Multiple func parameters for LINQ - EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, func

I was fiddling around with the linq its `Func` parameter(on entity framework). Then I found out this behaviour

```
var idMatchQuery = new Func<MyClass, bool>(x => x.Id == someId);
var statusMatchQuery = new Func<MyClass, bool>(x => x.Status == someStatus);

/// works
var a = myClassEntity.FirstOrDefault(idMatchQuery);

/// doesn't work
var b = myClassEntity.FirstOrDefault(p => idMatchQuery(p) && statusMatchQuery(p));

/// doesn't work
var c = myClassEntity.FirstOrDefault(p => idMatchQuery(p) && p.Status == 1);
```

It throws `UnsupportedOperationException` since the `EF` does not recognize those queries. I could have accept it much easier if none of the above were not working. But it bugs me when it works with one and only one `Func` query, but not with combinations with other queries.

I'm sure there exist an explanation for it, but I guess my search terms were too naive for the answer I'm looking for.

What is the explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Whether the first version "works" is debatable, because it resolves to `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` call, not the `Queryable`, so it will bring the whole table in memory before applying your func, which I guess is not what you expect.

Comment: well if thats the case I am not even feeling okay now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is caused that, EF should translate your predicate to TSQL language. You can check, that parameter of `FirstOrDefault` method is not `Func<T, bool>`, but instead `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, because last one give us oppotunity to parse it and translate to TSQL. When you use two `Func<T, bool>` or `Func<T, bool>` with simple condition EF can't translate and parse it to TSQL due to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` inner stuff and features complexity, that is why EF keep this predicates at origin state and send to server as it was written at first, as a result - `UnsupportedOperationException`. So, for EF - parse first predicate much more easily than other two.

**Conclusion**: it is caused by features and methodology of translation C# predicates from `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` to TSQL, because of it's sometimes enough high complexity.

Comment: I see. Sounds valid. Let me give it a shot, and I'll get back to you.